# While loop input MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, insert, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert users that is connected to a project. If it's not connected it shouldn't be inserted. But my query is inserting the same userid in all the projects.

PS. Its only two users connected to a project. So the insert should put in two insert for the project its connected too.

[Image of insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaYSl.png)

```
$getAdmin = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM users 
                        WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."'"); 

while($admininfo = mysql_fetch_array($getAdmin)) { 
    $getProsjekt = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                FROM cms_prosjekt 
                                WHERE area = '".$admininfo['area']."'"); 

    while($projectinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getProsjekt)) { 

        $getID = mysql_query("SELECT users.id FROM users 
                                LEFT JOIN cms_prosjekt ON cms_prosjekt.code= users.motto
                                WHERE cms_prosjekt.area = '".$projectinfo['area']."' AND rank = '1'
                                GROUP BY users.id"); 

        while($usersinfo = mysql_fetch_array($getID)) {     

            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO cms_messages 
                                    (type, userid, comment, posted_on, 
                                    author, status, code, area, title, 
                                    sentadmin, sentby, sentuser) 
                            VALUES ('areas', '".$usersinfo['id']."', 
                                    '".$mytextarea."', '".$posted_on."', 
                                    '".$admininfo['real_name']."', '0', 
                                    '".$projectinfo['code']."', 
                                    '".$admininfo['area']."', 
                                    '".$title."', '1', 
                                    '".$_SESSION['user']['id']."', 
                                    '0')") 
                        or die(mysql_error());
```

Any suggestions on my left join query?

Comment: please indent correctly your code... so unreadable we don't want to waste time reading it...

Comment: in some while MYSQL SELECT count of row i bigger then 1 and your while is repeat by your rows in table.

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: NOTE: Each While loop placed inside another while loop is like a Multiplication. loop1 = 2 rows, loop2 = 2 rows loop3 = 2 rows means your insert will run 2*2*2= 8 iterations

Comment: It is also very unclear a) what you are trying to do and b) what you are actually doing.